# How to write test for Promise that resolve fetched API in Angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

I wrote a Weather API in Angular. I have a service that fetch data from API and then the data are inject in a component that display them on the page.

Service:

```
    getForecastWeatherData(location: Location, target?: string) {
        this.setParams(location, target);
        return this.http.get<ForecastWeatherAPI>(`${this.apiUrl}forecast/daily?`, {
            params: this.urlParams,
        });
    }
```

Component:

```
showForecastWeather(): Promise<boolean> {
        return new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {
            this.forecastSubscription = this.data
                .getForecastWeatherData(this.location, this.target)
                .subscribe({
                    next: (response) => {
                        if (response) {
                            this.forecastWeather = response;
                            resolve(true);
                        } 
                    },
                    error: () => this.showErrorMsgBox(),
                });
        });
    }
```

I tried to write a unit test which check that data are properly render on the website. I have a problem how to do it properly.

```
it('should render forecast and current weather', fakeAsync(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(WeatherComponent);
    let component = fixture.componentInstance;
    let element = fixture.debugElement;
    component.showForecastWeather();
    const forecast = element.queryAll(By.css('.forecast'));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(forecast).toBeTruthy();
    expect(forecast.length).toBe(16);
    flushMicrotasks();
}));
```

Comment: I guess the first question would be; why use a Promise here if you already have an observable?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Promises when you have rxjs and observables. But any case, the way you are doing unit test is not right anyways. You should mock the services in the component that you are testing like this;

```
describe('', () => {
  let data = jasmine.createSpyObj('YourService', ['getForecastWeatherData']);
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers:[
        {provide: YourService, useValue: data},
      ],...
    })

})
```

and expect a mock request like this;

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(IdentitySetComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    data.getWeatherForecast.and.returnValue(of({result:'expected response'}))
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

For your promises, use **flushMicroTasks**. So;

```
  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    flushMicrotasks();
    //and your expectations...
  });
```

Comment: hmm ... I choosed Promise because I fetch data from 2 API and then I fire change detection and the page scroll to the section with loaded data. Mayby it was a mistake?

Comment: You can use rxjs operators like forkJoin, concatMap, switchMap, combineLatest. You can pick one of these depending on your situation. You never need promises when you have rxjs.

Comment: Thank a lot for your sugestion. I've started lerning Angular few month ago and I still think in 'Vanilla Js'